# how can get response from <form target="IFrame"> 

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

There is a simple web page which sends request, handles & manipulated by a servlet class and send back the response `text`.while i want `ajax` type handleing the request at client side that is why i am giving the response target to a invsible iframe. ***but i want to print `success` on the page after iframe gets the response ***

```
<html> <body>
<form action="test" method="post" target="IFrame"> /*response target is iframe*/
       <input type="text" name="logic" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<iframe name="IFrame" style="width:0; height:0"> </iframe>

</body>  </html>
```

i think this can be done using `javascript` or  `jquery`, please guid me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

In the page which loads in the iframe, you will need to invoke a parent function.

```
<!-- This is the Parent.  Call it JSTest1.html -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parentAlert() {
        alert('hey there from the parent');
    }
</script>
I'm the parent
<iframe src="/JSTest2.html"></iframe>
</body>

<!-- this is the iframe html loaded.  Call it JSTest2.html-->
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        window.parent.parentAlert();
    });
</script>
In the Iframe.
</body>
```

Comment: didn't work for me. i checked using `firebug` when page loads, i don't see any `fn` inside of iframe.

Comment: I just tested the update with firebug and it seems to work.  The idea is that the iframe won't tell you when it's loaded.  So, in the html the iframe loads, you need to emit javascript that will call a function on the containing page.

Answer (score 1):

To send a message from Iframe to Parent window page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    //Message part is two parts Event name and Data you want to send
    // Example message = "my_action,my_data"
    message = "my_action,my_data" 
    parent.postMessage(message, "*");
  });
</script>
```

At the parent window you can do the following to listen to this message and capture it:

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
  // Youe message which you send is captured here in e.data will split it on ',' to get the event and the data  
  message = e.data.split(',')[0]
  value = e.data.split(',')[1]
  if ( message === "my_action" ) {
      myParentFunction(value)
  }     
},false);
```